# Verb or phrase for "to make an onomatopoeia"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, onomatopoeia

In the event that a common, recognized, and understood onomatopoeia for a sound does not already exist, how would you phrase the creation of an onomatopoeia for the sound?

Essentially the word `onomatopoeize` would fit the bill, but I can't find that in a dictionary.

You can see examples of `onomatopoeize` being used online [if you Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=onomatopoeize&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=onomatopoeize&nfpr=1), but as of today there are only 75 hits for that word. This leads me to believe that other people have also struggled to find a verb for this and have "created" `onomatopoeize` as it is easy to deduce what the intent of the term is even though it isn't a "real" word.

An example of this is on [Consumerist's article "Coca-Cola Blāk Effervescent Coffee Crap Debut"](http://consumerist.com/2006/03/21/coca-cola-blk-effervescent-coffee-crap-debut/):

> The macron over Blāk was specially designed by Coca-Cola scientists to help onomatopoeize the sound you’ll make after drinking the concoction.

Is there a proper, non-colloquial English word for this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it, use *onomatopoeize*. The suffix *-ize* is a productive suffix in English. People neologize words for their needs and they are not always in dictionaries. As for the phrase, you already found one: *to make an onomatopoeia*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no verb form of *onomatopoeia*, I think ***[imitate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/imitate)*** can express the concept you are referring to:

> - to make or be like; resemble or simulate.

- The macron over Blāk was specially designed by Coca-Cola scientists to help ***imitate*** the sound you’ll make after drinking the concoction.

Comment: **Mimic** is another synonym.

Comment: The only reason I don't like `imitate` as compared to `onomatopoeize` or `to make an onomatopoeia` is that the meaning of imitate is looser, and can be interpreted in a more broad sense.

For example, I can imitate a mime; that definitely wouldn't involve an imitation of the sound made, nor is it a valid replacement of the idea of expressing a sound by making an onomatopoeia. It has a more general understanding, rather than the specific intent of `to make an onomatopoeia`.

Comment: Ok, but you asked for "a proper non-colloquial English word" !!! Anyway it is ok if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Some people have already coined "[onomatopoeify](http://imulsify.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/russian-circles-memorial-2013.html)" and "[onomatopoeiafy](http://forums.webosnation.com/palm-pre-pre-plus/249525-official-webos-1-4-5-anticipation-thread-29.html)".  I prefer the former, although neither has any significant usage.

Comment: Interesting. Side note, Russian Circles rock!